# Panels - custom or use System?

Tags: panels

Maybe I'm not getting this but for Page manager (Panels) there is two options to create a page either Custom Page or use the System (Node Template).

I need to create a Panel for the news page (/news). I could either create a Custom one and set the path to "/news" OR use the System node_view page and create a Variant where if the ***Selection rule = This panel will be selected if Current path is "news".***

Which way is better? Should I overload the System with many variants where one of them checks if the Current path is "news" or create my own Custom Page for the news page?

[image]

Comment: I can't tell you which is better, but if /news is a node, then it's probably easier to override the system node template. Also you should use the real path instead of path alias when defining a selection rule, meaning `node/XXX` instead of `news`

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, you should _not_ have variants based on the URL, but on the content type.

Comment: You will only override a system path if you want to change the default behaviour of the path (routing or display), and normally only for a specific context attached to the entity on that path (example: showing an enhanced 'article' to 'editors').

Answer (score 0):

A page provides a certain context.

For `node_view`, it happens to be a node.

There's no benefit to creating a custom page just to provide the same context.

You'd want to add a new page however, if you, for example, wanted both a node and a taxonomy term as context.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of which one is better, but what you are trying to achieve.

- If you want to change what the system does when people view a node
  `/node/%node`, then you need to make a variant on that system page.
- If you want to make a new page that does something different like
  `/news` then you need a custom page.

Each page listed in Page Manager must have a different URL, each    variant within a page will have the same URL (except for arguments    `%mandatory` and `!optional`).

So you actually *cannot* have a variant for `news` inside the `node/%node` system page.

---

One of the most common uses for a custom page is to display a view, which is what I assume your `/news` page to be.